# Laravel Homestead: 'homestead init' -> could not open input file

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install the latest version of Laravel Homestead on my PC and when I try running the command `homestead init` in my command terminal, I keep getting a "Could not open input file" error.

Steps I've taken so far with installing Laravel Homestead:

1) Created a new directory at **C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Code**
2) Installed Composer 
3) Installed VirtualBox and Vagrant Box 
4) In 'cmd', ran the command `vagrant box add laravel/homestead`
5) Copied the Composer files from **C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin** into my **C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Code** directory.
 
6) In 'cmd', ran the command `composer global require "laravel/homestead=~2.0"`

Since I am following the [Laravel homestead installation guide](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/homestead) the next step is to copy the `~/.composer/vendor/bin` directory to my PATH so that the `homestead` command is executable but this is where I get confused.

I have tried a couple of things but they have not worked for me.

In my **~/.composer/vendor/bin** directory, I have copied the **homestead** directory files into my **C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Code** directory but when I try running the command `homestead init`, I keep getting the error **Could not open input file: C:\Users\Jeff\Desktop\Code/../laravel/homestead/homestead**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Windows use `homestead.bat init` instead of `homestead init`.